# C++ appears to be significantly slower than both Python Ruby for Project Euler

Tags: python, c++, ruby, performance, algorithm

I have 3 solutions to the following problem from Project Euler.

> If p is the perimeter of a right angle triangle with integral length
>   sides, {a,b,c}, there are exactly three solutions for p = 120.
>
> {20,48,52}, {24,45,51}, {30,40,50}
>
> For which value of p ≤ 1000, is the number of solutions maximised?

My three solutions for each language are available below.

C++:

```
boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_time = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
map<int, int> square_lookup;
for(int i=0; i<= 1500; i++) {
    square_lookup[i*i] = i ;
}
auto end_time = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

Python2:

```
start = time.time()
res = range(1, 1501)
squares = {}
#square_lookups = dict(zip([x*x for x in res], res))
square_lookups = {}
for x in range(1, 1501):
    square_lookups[x*x] = x
end = time.time()
```

Ruby:

```
start_time = Time.now

square_lookup = {}
(1 .. 1500).map {|x| x*x}.each_with_index do |square, root|
    square_lookup[square] = root+1
end

end_time = Time.now
```

Timings on a quadcore i5:

```
> lookup gen time: 0.00141787528992 
> Python Result: 840 Time:
> 0.282248973846
> 
> Lookup gen time 4640960 nanoseconds 
> C++: Result: 840 : Time: 695301578 nanoseconds
> 
> 
> Lookup gen time 0.000729416
> Ruby: Result: 840 Time: 0.149393345
```

The lookup gen time is the time it takes to construct a hash table with 1500 elements, with the keys being a perfect square and the values being their respective roots.

Even in this respect, C++ is still **SLOWER** than both Python and Ruby. I realize I may have the most efficient solution overall and for each language, but using the same types of operations still show C++ as being extremely slow.

**IMPORTANT EDIT** I changed `map` to use `unordered_map` for the C++ solution, however it is still slower!

Modified C++ file: http://pastebin.com/2YyB6Rfm

```
lookup gen time: 0.00134301185608
Python Result: 840 Time: 0.280808925629

Lookup gen time 2021697 nanoseconds
C++: Result: 840 : Time: 392731891 nanoseconds

Lookup gen time 0.000729313
Ruby: Result: 840 Time: 0.148183345
```

Comment: No, the problem is solved, I'm asking why the C++ implementation is slower.

Comment: why do you use boost/chrono library when there is already a chronos library?

Comment: Why do you comment with useless comments that have nothing to do with my question?

Comment: With what optimization setting did you compile?

Comment: Before with none, and now I used both -02 and -03 which made the code a lot faster.

Comment: @ViktorChynarov: The C++ standard library is notoriously slow without optimization. (As is most of the C++ code I write.)

Comment: What is "integral length sides"?

Comment: integral length sides
 are integers that can be written without fractional or decimal component, don't be alarmed by the "integral".

Comment: gcc's -O flag describes the level of optimisation you want, from -O0 to -O3 ... therefore your should not used both -O2 and -O3 ! Just choose one (-O3 is suppose faster) and only put the one you decided to use

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code has another serious problem--much more serious than `map` vs. `unordered_map` (at least IMO).

In particular, where you do:

```
int result = square_lookup[(i*i) + (j*j)];

if(result)  {
    int perimeter = i + j + result;
    if(perimeter <= 1000) {
        occurences[perimeter] += 1;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't just look for the value `i*i+j*j` in the existing map. Rather, if a key isn't present in the map, it inserts a node in the map with `i*i+j*j` as the key, and `0` (or, more specifically, a value-initialized object of the map's `value_type`, which is `int` in this case) into the map.

Inserting nodes in the map for all those values you don't care about is quite slow. What you're trying to do here is really just check whether the value is already in the map. For that, you can use code like this:

```
auto result = square_lookup.find(i*i + j*j);

if (result!=square_lookup.end())  {
    int perimeter = i + j + result->second;
    if (perimeter <= 1000) 
        ++occurences[perimeter];                
}
```

This uses `find` to find whether a key is in the map. Then if (and only if) the key is in the map, it looks up the value currently associated with that key.

This gives a substantial improvement in speed--to about 20-30 ms with either VC++ or g++.

With this change in place, the difference between `map` and `unordered_map` also shrinks away. Code using `map` can still run in ~20-30 milliseconds. The code using `unordered_map` may be just a tiny bit faster on average, but my system clock only has 10 ms granularity, so I'd really have to test with more data to say for sure.

For reference, here's the code as I ran it (note that I did some other general cleanup of the code, but nothing else should have any major effect on speed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <chrono>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto start_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    map<int, int> square_lookup;
    int ctr = 0;
    generate_n(inserter(square_lookup, square_lookup.end()),
        1500,
        [&]() { ++ctr;  return make_pair(ctr*ctr, ctr); });

    auto end_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cout << "Lookup gen time "
        << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << "\n";

    map<int, int> occurences;
    typedef std::pair<int, int> const &map_t;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= 1000; j++) {
            auto result = square_lookup.find(i*i + j*j);

            if (result != square_lookup.end())  {
                int perimeter = i + j + result->second;
                if (perimeter <= 1000)
                    ++occurences[perimeter];
            }
        }
    }

    auto it = std::max_element(occurences.begin(), occurences.end(), 
        [](map_t a, map_t b) { return a.second < b.second; });

    end_time = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << "C++: Result: " << it->first << " : Time: "
        << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << "\n";
}
```

Summary: in C++ the `[]` operator on `map` will insert an item if it's not already present. That can be handy, but it's not always what you want. If you only want to retrieve a value if it's already present, it's *not* the right tool for the job--and `.find` can be substantially faster.

Once you correct that problem, the difference between `map` and `unordered_map` (at least mostly) disappears.

Comment: `make_pair(ctr, ctr*ctr)` - shouldn't it be the reverse order?

Comment: @T.C.: Oops--yes, indeed it should. Thank you.

Comment: @ViktorChynarov: It's unfortunate that the code from the original question to which this answer refers is no longer visible (short of going into the edit history of the question and then following a pastebin link).

Answer (score 9):

You claim you're timing

> The lookup gen time is the time it takes to construct a **hash table** with 1500 elements, with the keys being a perfect square and the values being their respective roots.

That is true for the Python and Ruby solutions, but in the C++ example you're constructing a `std::map<int, int>`. That is *not* a hash table - it is a red black tree. Inserting and lookup is `O(lg N)`, not `O(1)`.

To get a fair comparison, you want to use `std::unordered_map<int, int>` as your type. That is a real hash table.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the instances of map to unordered_map, but it's still slower. 


C++: Result: 840 : Time: 392731891 nanoseconds

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations? (i.e., did you pass `-O2` or `-O3` to the compiler?) Also, for best results with a `std::unordered_map`, set the maximum load factor to something sensible before using it. For example, `yourmap.max_load_factor(0.75);`

Comment: I now compiled with both -O2 and -O3 and it made it a lot faster. Around 0.12 seconds, changing the max_load_factor to 0.75 made a difference (from 0.15 without changing).